# Is there a way to transfer 'this' to a different function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have an instance where I need the value of `this` to be transferred over to a different function for use. The obvious solution would be to use global variables, but I have heard that that is not good practice. Here is my code:

```
$('.title').each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(){
       titleThis = this;
   });  
});

$('.post-footer').click(function(){
    $(titleThis).css('background','red');
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4ycajp0/)

**How can I do this without using global variables?**

Side note: I can't do something like this:

```
$('.title').each(function(){
       $(this).click(function(){
           var titleThis = this;
           $('.post-footer').click(function(){
               $(titleThis).css('background','red');
           });
       });  
    });
```

because the plugin I am using in place of `.click()` in this example (JQuery Waypoints) throws an error when I try to stack it (not sure why). It works fine when I use the global variable in my first example, I would just like to avoid using global variables if at all possible.

EDIT:
Since there seem to be some issues with my example code that some solutions won't work in my real code, here's my actual code block:

```
    $('.title').each(function() {
            //creating the waypoint
          $(this).waypoint(function(direction) {
//declaring global variable as this
              titleThis = this;
              //if below waypoint, do animation
              if (direction === "down"){
                  //fix the title
                  $(this.element).addClass('titleFixed');
                  //slide right
                  $(this.element).animate({left:'10%'},250,function(){
                      //slide title decoration right
                      $(this).next().animate({left:'0'},50);
                  });
                  //if above waypoint, undo animation
              }else{
                  //unfix the title
                  $(this.element).removeClass('titleFixed');
                  //animate left
                  $(this.element).animate({left:'-3.5%'},240,function(){
                      //animate title direction left
                    $(this).next().animate({left:'-3.5%'},150);
                  });
              }
          });
        });
      $('.post-footer').waypoint(function() {
         $(titleThis.element).css('background','red');
      });
```

If I try to nest the second .waypoint function inside the first, I get an error.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish (from a functionality perspective, not a "this" context perspective)? That will allow us to provide better insight.

Comment: With JQuery waypoints, I am trying to make the currently active `.title` turn red when `.post-footer` waypoint is reached. Since all of the titles only have one class, I need to use `this` to select the current one.

Comment: You might consider adding the click handler only when the .title block is clicked, and removing it after the .post-footer is clicked. This would allow you to avoid global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need global variables. Just wrap your code in a self-executing function:

```js
(function(){
    var titleThis;
    $('.title').click(function(){
        titleThis = this;
    });
    $('.post-footer').click(function(){
        $(titleThis).css('background','red');
    });
})();
// `titleThis` is not defined here.
```

Comment: I've never encountered this before! Strange. Thanks anyhow, TIL!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with using a global variable when it's necessary. What's wrong is the overuse of global variables when passing the value (or reference) as a function parameter is more appropriate. That's not your case though since the click handler on $(.post-footer) is triggered independently and does not share variable scope with the click handlers of $(.title)

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with your code. But it's completely alright to use a global variable to mark which div was clicked the last. If that's what you're shooting for.

I would just suggest declaring and defining the global variable first:

```
var titleThis = null;
```

Comment: "*the click handler on `$(.post-footer)` [...] does not share variable scope with the click handlers of `$(.title)`*". Then you can create that scope, instead of using the global one.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to do it with just css and adding a .selected class for you to target.

```
$('.title').each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(){
       $('.title.selected').removeClass('selected'); // Prevents having multiples selected.
       $(this).addClass('selected')
   });  
});

$('.post-footer').click(function(){
    $('.title').css('background', ''); // Undo css on previous titles
    $('.title.selected').css('background','red');
});
```